# Maven says that there is now dependency despite the fact that it exists

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project of two modules and I need to use the class from the first one in the another one. for this I added dependency to the pom file of the first:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.mdnaRabbit.worker</groupId>
      <artifactId>Worker</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
```

when the pom of the module I'm trying to add is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>DLP</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mdnaRabbit.worker</groupId>
  <artifactId>Worker</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Worker</name>
```

when I'm importing the class to the first class like this:

```
import com.mdnaRabbit.worker.data.Data;
```

and trying to execute packaging I have the following trace:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/NewTask/src/main/java/com/mdnaRabbit/newt/App.java:[9,33] error: package com.mdnaRabbit.worker.data does not exist
[ERROR] /home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/NewTask/src/main/java/com/mdnaRabbit/newt/App.java:[39,19] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class App
/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/NewTask/src/main/java/com/mdnaRabbit/newt/App.java:[27,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class App
/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/NewTask/src/main/java/com/mdnaRabbit/newt/App.java:[40,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class App
/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/NewTask/src/main/java/com/mdnaRabbit/newt/App.java:[40,24] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 5 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
```

the import string is not underlined with red

Comment: Have you run 'mvn install' on the project you're depending on?

Comment: Are you building the parent module or the child module? Did you ever executed mvn install on Worker module?

Comment: Oh, NilsH, thank you. I'm constantly forgetting about running "mvn install".

Comment: You need to tell that, you are new to maven.

Comment: And you are perfectly right. I'm new to programming at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**: I needed to run "mvn install"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mdnaRabbit.worker</groupId>
    <artifactId>WORKER</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
          <!-- parameters and values common to all goals, as required -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or try installing manually.